# Can't read an .xlsx file with [BlobInput]

Tags: azure, azure-functions, blob

I'm trying to read an `.xlsx` file from blob storage but the only option I have is to read it as a string from the binding parameter.

```
[BlobInput("templates/myTemplate.xlsx", Connection = "StorageAccountConnStr")] string template
```

To load the `.xlsx` file I need to make a MemoryStream. Thus I wrote:

```
var templateBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(template);
var templateStream = new MemoryStream(templateBytes);
```

It fails and tells me the file might be corrupt.

Any ideas how to read properly an .xlsx file from blob storage as an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, except `string`, `byte[]` is supported.
Therefore I could be able to read and open my file. Azure documentation does not mention it yet.